# How to tag that a class is thread-safe (or not)?

Tags: c#, documentation, attributes, thread-safety

In MSDN documentation we see :

[Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43zwz7ys(v=VS.100).aspx)

> Thread Safety
>
> This type is thread safe.

[TextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx)

> Thread Safety
>
> Any public static
> (Shared in Visual Basic) members of
> this type are thread safe. Any
> instance members are not guaranteed to
> be thread safe.

I've developed a similar (static) class to the Console one, so how can I tag it to thread safe? I'm extracting XML documentation and I would know how I can this part like in the MSDN Doc'.

Hope I'm clear enough...

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this detail to the [`<summary>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d6dt3kf.aspx) or [`<remarks>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zw4z1ys.aspx) tags.

There is no specific tag or convention on how to indicate a class is thread safe - you need to write it in your documentation.

Comment: Wasn't me - but maybe because the <threadsafety/> tag is what's needed.

Comment: You can still add `<threadsafety>` and VS won't complain.  If you are using _GhostDoc_ then it will pick it up and include it when it generates any help files.

Answer (score 23):

The [Sandcastle Help File Builder](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB) project contains a useful [XML Comments Guide](http://ewsoftware.github.io/XMLCommentsGuide).

It [documents the `threadsafety` tag](http://ewsoftware.github.io/XMLCommentsGuide/html/fb4625cb-52d0-428e-9c7c-7a0d88e1b692.htm):

```
<threadsafety static="true|false" instance="true|false"/>
```

The root SHFB documentation page is [here](http://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB).